# How to resolve merge conflicts on pull request from forked repo

Tags: git, github, gitlab, git-merge, pull-request

I forked a repo (lets call it `original repo`), did some changes on a branch in my project (lets call it `my changes`) and now I am trying to pull the changes `my changes` back into the `original repo`.

I submitted a pull request to `original repo` and now there are `merge conflicts`. I have been advised to solve the merge conflicts in `my changes`. How would I go on about this?

I assume in order to do that, I need to pull the `original repo` into `my changes` and solve the conflicts locally. However, how would I pull a repo I only forked into my repo?

Comment: cd into `my changes` then run `git rebase original repo`, begin to resolve conflicts. depending on the editor/IDE you are using and the number of changes this can be done fairly easily

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem, here how to solve:

1 - Checkout to branch `master` of your forked repo; 
2 - Make a pull from original repository `git pull https://github.com/ORIGINAL_OWNER/ORIGINAL_REPOSITORY.git BRANCH_NAME`; 
3 - Resolve conflicts in your forked repository; 
4 - Then submit back the PR;